# cast from 'Unmanaged<CFData>!'to unrelated type 'NSData' always fails

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

[image: I want read address book avatar,but it's CFData class,How to convert into NSData class]

I want read address book avatar,but it's CFData class,How to convert into NSData class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification

Comment: Consider that `ABAddressBook` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an `a: A`. Casting `a as B` can only ever work if

- `A` is a subtype of `B` (the compiler will realize that this case *always* works) or
- `B` is a subtype of `A` (which *may* work, depending on the actual type of `a`).

You are trying to cast between to types that are not in such a relation ("unrelated type").

Be careful with `as!`, too. That tells the compiler: "I know this will work, don't worry about it!". If it turns out you were wrong (or just trying to get around having to deal with the optional `as` will give you) you will get a runtime error, something you should always try to avoid.